# Docker fails to start container occasionally with error "lstat /dev/dm-1: no such file or directory"

Tags: python, jenkins, docker

I have a Jenkins data pipeline and will invoke start 40 docker containers every day. Every now and then (about every 5 days) one of these 40 containers failed to start itself and had some weird messages as below:

> time="2015-04-29T03:09:31-07:00" level="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 9d9b2b12654731aceb69279e18f083e337456a13ffbb2ffc8426932fdf22c323: lstat /dev/dm-1: no such file or directory"

The docker file I use is as below:

```
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER XX(XX@XX.COM)
ADD requirements* /home/

RUN yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"

RUN yum install -y epel-release

RUN yum install -y python-devel python-pip zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel libxml2-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel

RUN pip install virtualenv

RUN virtualenv virtual_env_1
RUN source virtual_env_1/bin/activate && pip install -r /home/requirements.txt
```

The docker command I run is as below(from jenkins):

> docker run -v ${WORKSPACE}:/image_folder --privileged=true image_name sh -c 'source virtual_env_1/bin/activate && cd /image_folder/src/ && python app.py'

Did you guys see this issue before? What do you think is the problem?

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Are you using the device mapper storage driver?

Comment: It's probably a bug, see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12618 and https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4306, although they don't look identical. I would make sure your kernel and docker versions are up-to-date and if it still persists, file a bug.

Comment: @Adrian Mouat Yes I used -v to bind a local workspace to running container. Do you think that's the problem?

Comment: I *think* it's a device mapper bug. The device mapper driver is used for the UFS (the default container storage) so I don't think it's related to using `-v`.

Comment: @Adrian Mouat OK thanks.. I don't know how to file this bug because it really seems to happen randomly in my Jenkins build so I have no idea how to reproduce it. Thanks for your help.